# HTML5: Custom Tags Vs. Classes

Tags: html, css

I just read about the HTML5 - Custom Tags again and got a question about it.

[W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_browsers.asp) says:

> **Adding New Elements to HTML**
>
> You can add any new element to HTML with a browser trick: This example
>   adds a new element called `<myHero>` to HTML, and defines a display >
>   style for it:
>
> ```
> <!DOCTYPE html>
> <html>
>
> <head>
>   <title>Creating an HTML Element</title>
>   <script>document.createElement("myHero")</script>
>   <style>
>   myHero {
>     display: block;
>     background-color: #ddd;
>     padding: 50px;
>     font-size: 30px;
>   } 
>   </style> 
> </head>
>
> <body>
>
> <h1>My First Heading</h1>
>
> <p>My first paragraph.</p>
>
> <myHero>My First Hero</myHero>
>
> </body>
> </html>
> ```

For me this sounds like the use of those custom tags is the same like classes.
What is the added Value of custom tags?
Is there any situation in that I should use custom tags instead of classes?
Or maybe is it always better to use classes?

I just feel like everything new in HTML5 has a good reason and makes HTML better in some way.

Only the use of custom tags seems meaningless to me so I wonder when to use them and why.

So please teach me how to use it properly.

Comment: I don't think any spec specifies that we can use or create custom HTML tags

Comment: I guess when you don't care about semantic, or when they're gonna be replaced by other valid html tags by some engine like polymer

Comment: There's actually a lot of things you "can do" in HTML that are just highly discouraged because they reduce interoperability, or could have completely unexpected consequences when the W3C decides to make "myNameChoice" an official spec-driven type. Honestly, I also wouldn't use W3Schools as a frequent reference; despite what you might think, they are not directly related to W3C.

Comment: Plus, in my experience with W3Schools, the code is incorrect half the time

Comment: @Mr.Alien See http://www.w3.org/TR/custom-elements/. It should be `<my-hero>` instead of `<myHero>`, tough.

Comment: @JacobGray - I know everybody likes to hate on W3Schools because they aren't officially related to any W3 organizations, and I would recommend MDN over them any day of the week and twice on Sunday, but I've never come across incorrect code "half the time" on W3Schools, and I actually find them to do a reasonably good job of staying current with the latest specs.

Comment: @adam it was just a figure of speech :) but seriously,  at least earlier on, I would have a lot of problems with their coding. Obviously,  though, it was not half the time :D

Comment: @Adam
By MDN you mean the Mozilla Developer Network?

Comment: Yes that's what he means. By the way, @Adam - most people don't hate on W3Schools because of a lack of affiliation. The hate is for the quality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Custom Elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/custom-elements) module of HTML5 standardizes this idea, allowing you to use [custom elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/custom-elements/#dfn-custom-element):

> **Custom element** is [platform object](http://www.w3.org/TR/WebIDL/#dfn-platform-object) whose [interface](http://www.w3.org/TR/WebIDL/#dfn-interface) is defined by the author. The [interface prototype object](http://www.w3.org/TR/WebIDL/#interface-prototype-object) of a
>   [custom element](http://www.w3.org/TR/custom-elements/#dfn-custom-element)'s [interface](http://www.w3.org/TR/WebIDL/#dfn-interface) is called the **custom element
>   prototype**.
>
> The **custom element type** identifies a [custom element](http://www.w3.org/TR/custom-elements/#dfn-custom-element)
>   [interface](http://www.w3.org/TR/WebIDL/#dfn-interface) and is a sequence of characters that must match the
>   [NCName](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xml-names-19990114/#NT-NCName) production, must contain a U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS character,
>   and must not contain any [uppercase ASCII letters](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/infrastructure.html#uppercase-ascii-letters).

Therefore, you could use `<my-hero>`, but not `<myHero>`.

> [**Motivations**](http://www.w3.org/TR/custom-elements/#motivations)
>
> There are two motivations that fueled the development of this
>   specification:
>
> - **Provide a way for Web developers to build their own, fully-featured DOM elements**. Though it was long possible to create
>     DOM elements with any tag names in HTML, these elements weren't very
>     functional. By giving Web developers the means to both inform the
>     parser on how to properly construct an element and to react to
>     lifecycle changes of an element, the specification eliminates the need
>     for DOM-as-a-render-view scaffolding that has to exist today in most
>     web frameworks or libraries.
> - **Rationalize the platform**. The specification ensures that all of its new features and abilities are in concert with how the relevant
>     bits of the Web platform work today, so that these new features could
>     be used to explain the functionality of existing Web platform
>     features, such as HTML elements.
>
> Most of the effort went into finding the right balance between the two
>   motivations, driven by the hope that these motivations do not run
>   counter to each other, but are rather complementary parts of the same
>   larger story. For example, though the scope of the spec is currently
>   limited to only creating custom elements by authors, it is designed to
>   shorten the distance to a much more ambitious goal of rationalizing
>   all HTML, SVG, and MathML elements into one coherent system.

Comment: Thx for this answer. Sounds to me like there is no special case (maybe later but not now) when I should use custom elements instead of classes. Right?

Comment: @Nils If you use custom elements, you can define a custom prototype. Adding or removing classes doesn't change the prototype of an element. So custom elements may be very useful. But in most cases you can probably find workarounds with classes.

Comment: Alright, thank you very mutch.

Answer (score 1):

There are no benefits to a custom tag over a class and they should not be used.

Creating a tag in this way is not part of HTML5, it is just DOM manipulation with Javascript.

Custom elements are a different matter http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/